# What are the origins of "what's up"?

Tags: etymology

How did this begin? Did it really start with Bugs Bunny?

Comment: What did you edit in my question. It looks just the way it was

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/22021/revisions

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

### OED

The Oxford English Dictionary says this colloquial use of the adverb *up* is very frequent from circa 1850, long before Bugs Bunny's 1940 debut. Two citations:

> 1838 E. C. Gaskell Let. 19 Aug. (1966) 37, I did not
>   mention a word to Lucy but she must have
>   guessed something was ‘up’.
>
> 1851 H. Mayhew London Labour I. 19/1 A shout in answer from the other asks ‘What's up?’

---

### Antedatings

I found an antedating from **1813** in [*The history and adventures of Godfrey Ranger*](http://books.google.com/books?id=L6oBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA121&dq=%22what%27s%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S9xFUauPC6by4QS12YEw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22what%27s%20up%22%20&f=false) by David William Paynter:

[image: Seeing such a large body of people before him, and being struck with the incessant moans that issued from every quarter, he made a sudden stand ; and staring around him with stupid amazement, exclaimed, "Soul o' my body, what's up here?"]

And an **1819** in *[Right about face; or, Ben the Gordon boy](http://books.google.fi/books?id=gUcDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA124&dq=%22what%27s%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S9xFUauPC6by4QS12YEw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22what%27s%20up%22%20&f=false)* by Emily Brodie:

[image: The child had fainted, and after some minutes, much to Bob's relief, opened her eyes. " What's up with you, Nell ? " he asked kindly. " I's so tired ; carry me home, Bob." And so Bob did, wondering greatly what could have come over his little sister.]

Comment: I've sent these antedatings to the [OED](http://www.oup.com/uk/oedsubform/).

Answer (score 5):

As reported by [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what%27s_up), *what's up* has been made popular by the cartoon character Bugs Bunny, who used it as part of his catch phrase "What’s up Doc?" (around 1940).
*Whatsup* was used in the short story "[The adventures of Shamrock Jolnes](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/1918/)" from O' Henry (September 11, 1862 - June 5, 1910).

> "Good morning, Whatsup," he said, without turning his head. "I'm glad to notice that you've had your house fitted up with electric lights at last."

*What's up* is used in "[The Sea-Wolf](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1074/1074-h/1074-h.htm)", written by Jack London and published in 1904.

> "What’s up?" I asked Wolf Larsen, unable longer to keep my curiosity in check.
>
> "Never mind what’s up," he answered gruffly.  "You won’t be a thousand years in finding out, and in the meantime just pray for plenty of wind."

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I don't think Wiktionary is a very reliable source.

Comment: Besides, Wiktionary doesn't claim that it began with Bugs Bunny.

Comment: @Kiam Your first example is a NAME - a spoof off Watson.

Comment: @mplungjan Did I say it was not a name?

Comment: No, but it is a bit strange as Etymology for "What's Up"

Comment: @mplungjan In fact, it is not the etymology of _what's up_; I simply reported where _whatsup_ was used. Basing on the title of the short story, it's probably clear that Whatsup is a joke on the name Watson used in the Conan Doyle's stories. It is probably true that Whatsup should not had been chosen if _what's up_ were not an already used expression.

Comment: @Lelouch Lamperouge Wiktionary is much better than any source you supplied.

Answer (score 2):

I would derive "What's up?" from "What matter/problem has come up?".