# What does the "up" mean in "what's up"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I once stopped to think about exactly what I was saying, and, though I'd always known it didn't make sense, I realized I'd never questioned it before. Does it have its origin in a longer question that was cut short? Does it come from being concerned about a place or person that is literally higher than you? Or is it just an arbitrary preposition with no actual meaning and no real reason for being there?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22021/what-are-the-origins-of-whats-up

Comment: Absolutely, this question is not a duplicate of the suggested question above. The title is misleading, the older question is asking why it is used as a form of greeting.

Comment: Speculatively, even 1,000 years ago in any kind of formal meeting, say of a court or a company or a parish council, items ‘moved up’ the agenda until they 'came up' for discussion.

Finished with an item, the chairman asked the secretary: ‘What’s up next?’ then in many another context, ‘next’ was lost.

I agree with Mari-Lou… it's a different question that happens to be about the same phrase.